# C++ не выводится вещественное число

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include <sstream>
 using std::cout;
 using std::cin;
 using std::endl;
 using std::string;
 using std::stringstream;

 class questions {
  private:
   string name;
   string lastname;
   int rate_list[50];
   int rate_count;
   float middle;

  public:
   void read_name(){
    cout << "Your name" << endl;
    cin >> name;
 }
   string get_name(){
    return (name);
 }
   void read_lastname(){
    cout << "Your lastname" << endl;
    cin >> lastname;
    cin.ignore ();
   }
   string get_lastname(){
    return (lastname);
   }
   float get_middle(){
    return(middle);
   }

  void read_rate_list(){
  rate_count = 0;
  //rate_count ++;
  string rate_line, rate_word;
  int summa = 0;
  int value = 0;
  cout << "Enter your grades (separate by space)" << endl;
  cin.clear();
  getline(cin, rate_line);
  stringstream potok(rate_line);
  while (potok >> rate_word) {
   if (rate_word == "1" || rate_word == "2" || rate_word == "3" || rate_word == "4" || rate_word == "5") {
       //cout << rate_word;
       value = stoi(rate_word);
      // cout << value << endl;
       rate_list[rate_count] = value;
       summa += value;
       rate_count++;
    }
  }
  middle = summa / rate_count;
 }
 int* get_rate_list() {
 return(rate_list);
}

};
int main(){
 questions persone1;
 persone1.read_name();
 persone1.read_lastname();
 persone1.read_rate_list();
 cout << persone1.get_name() << endl;
 cout << persone1.get_lastname() << endl;
 cout  << persone1.get_middle() << endl;

// cout << persone1
```

}
Выводит целое число, а надо вещественное. 
Заранее спасибо

Comment: О каком числе идет речь???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы делите

```
summa / rate_count;
```

целое на целое - и деление получается целочисленное, т.е. дающее целое число...

Сделайте, например, так:

```
float(summa) / rate_count;
```